# CakePHP question: Getting value from app_controller.php to layout.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have set values in app_controller.php and i can use those variable in 'default.ctp'.

My question is: is it a good idea to get value from app_controller.php beforeRender() action ?

Is there any other alternative to get value in default.ctp ?

What's the pros and cons of passing value from app_controller.php - beforeRender() action to 'default.ctp' ?

Comment: what are these values used for?

Comment: This values are come from database as it's set in app_controller.php. These values are used to echo Html->link(..) etc

Comment: u have to use Configure::write($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is it a good idea to get value from app_controller.php beforeRender() action ?` It depends. Are you getting values from DB? If yes, do you have to get it from DB?

`Is there any other alternative to get value in default.ctp ?` If you don't say what kind of data, no one can answer that.

`What's the pros and cons of passing value from app_controller.php - beforeRender() action to 'default.ctp' ?` Compared to what?

Comment: Yes, getting value from database, and comparing with other options.